# Building a string one character at a time, check if it contains a neighbouring repeating substring

Tags: python, algorithm

Examples of invalid strings:
**AA**, AB**AA**, ABAC**AA**, **ABACABAC**, ABAC**ABAB**

Examples of valid strings:
AB, ABC, ABA, ABACABADAB, ABACABCACBABCABACABCACBACAB

I call this function every time I add a new character to the string. So strings like ABABC will never get checked by the function since the string will already be invalid once the second B is added.

I need the absolute **fastest** way to check this in a function.

So far I've come up with 2 relatively slow functions:

```py
def is_valid(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return True

    # Are last two chars the same
    if s[-1] == s[len(s)-2]:
        return False

    # Get array of indexes where last char appears and reverse it
    indexes = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(s[-1], s[:-1])]
    indexes = indexes[::-1]

    for index in indexes:
        a = s[index+1:]
        if index - len(a) + 1 < 0:
            return True
        b = s[index-len(a)+1 : index+1]
        if a == b: 
            return False

    return True
```

and

```py
def is_valid(s):
    # Reverse string
    s = s[::-1]

    substring = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        substring += s[i]

        if len(s) >= i+1+len(substring) and s[i+1 : i+1+len(substring)] == substring:
            return False

    return True
```

If there's not much to be improved here, would there be a noticable performance increase in C++/C# or Java?

Comment: Is ABBACA an invalid solution?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I believe that is invalid, because it contains `B` adjacent to another `B`.

Comment: Why? Is it a competition?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Its't not a competition, but I use this function in a O(N^2) algorithm and I can greatly improve it's speed by improving this functions speed.

Answer (score 2):

There is rather effective `O(nlogn)` algorithm  by Main and Lorentz to search for tandem repetitions.

Python translation from [this code](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/main_lorentz.html) returns only the fact of repeat.

```
def z_function(s):
    n = len(s)
    z = [0]*n
    l = 0
    r = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if (i <= r):
            z[i] = min (r-i+1, z[i-l])
        while (i+z[i] < n) and (s[z[i]] == s[i+z[i]]):
            z[i] += 1
        if (i+z[i]-1 > r):
            l = i
            r = i+z[i]-1
    return z

def get_z(z, i):
    return z[i] if 0<=i<len(z) else 0

def find_tandems(s, shift = 0):
    n =  len(s)
    if (n == 1):
        return False

    nu = n//2
    nv = n-nu
    u = s[:nu]
    v = s[nu:]
    ru = u[::-1]
    rv = v[::-1]

    if find_tandems (u, shift):
        return True
    if find_tandems (v, shift + nu):
        return True

    z1 = z_function (ru)
    z2 = z_function (v + '#' + u)
    z3 = z_function (ru + '#' + rv)
    z4 = z_function (v)
    for cntr in range(n):
        if (cntr < nu):
            l = nu - cntr
            k1 = get_z (z1, nu-cntr)
            k2 = get_z (z2, nv+1+cntr)

        else:
            l = cntr - nu + 1
            k1 = get_z (z3, nu+1 + nv-1-(cntr-nu))
            k2 = get_z (z4, (cntr-nu)+1)

        if (k1 + k2 >= l):
            return True
    return False

print(find_tandems("ABACABAC"))
print(find_tandems("ABACABADAB"))

>> True
>> False
```

Addition for incremental case:

```
def is_valid(s):
    s = s[::-1]
    z = z_function(s)
    for i in range(1,len(z)):
        if z[i]>=i:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Again, this is a correct solution, but instead of 20s (with either of my functions) this takes more than 2 minutes (didn't let it run till the end).

Comment: Your second function has quadratic complexity when no repeats and should work fast when short patterns. But does it look for **ending** repeats only?

Comment: I check the string every time I add a new character

Comment: Your function gives False for "ABAB" but True for  "ABABC"

Comment: And that is not a problem since that string would never be generated since it would fail before C was appended. I need to specify that in my original post.

Comment: Question does not mention incremental checking.

Comment: In case of incremental string constuction it's enough to make z_function for reversed string (linear time, perhaps instant update is possible).

Comment: I's love to see an example of how to do that and i'll test it as soon as possible.

Comment: z-function is ready in answer. As far as I understand - just check that `z[i]>=i for i>0`

Comment: Your addition for incremental case does give me the correct solution, but it takes about 36s to process a string of length 5000, where my other solution takes around 4.5s.

Comment: Sadly, z-function recalculates all the string at every step.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a regex:

```
import re


def is_valid(string):
    return re.search(r"(.+)\1", string) is None


invalids = ["AA", "ABAA", "ABACAA", "ABACABAC", "ABACABAB"]
print("All invalids are invalid", not any(is_valid(invalid) for invalid in invalids))

valids = ["AB", "ABC", "ABA", "ABACABADAB", "ABACABCACBABCABACABCACBACAB"]
print("All valids are valid", all(is_valid(valid) for valid in valids))
```

**Output**

```
All invalids are invalid True
All valids are valid True
```

The pattern `"(.+)\1"` tries to match a group of one or more characters followed by the same group.

Comment: While this is a correct solution, it's unfortunately much slower than either of my current solutions

Answer (score 0):

Use Okkonen's algorithm while building the string. When an active edge is engaged, a repeating neighbouring substring will occur as soon as the initial length of the edge is doubled. There's a beautiful visualisation of it that you can experiment with [here](https://brenden.github.io/ukkonen-animation/).